# Error loading javascript on footer (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, footer

I'm trying to optimize my company's website and now I'm trying to make wordpress load all the javascript on footer instead of the top of the web to make it faster loading the site.
I added this code to the function.php file:

```
// super easy way to move javascript to footer
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
```

The problem is that I'm using a slider plugin that is built-in with javascript and with this code it disappeared.

Does anybody knows how can I made to load all the javascript and jquery from my wordpress page on footer and that the slider doesn't disappeared?

The website url is www.contidosdixitais.com

Thanks so much

Comment: You're missing some code. Please share your actual functions. You should also be doing `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'function_name')`, not hooking into `wp_footer`.

Comment: I've no idea about javascript so I found this code on a tutorial. 
I installed a "Move Javascript to Footer" plugin that contains the same code in his php file so I decided to add it manually. 
The main problem is that everything is loaded at the end, and the slider doesn't work

Comment: I wasn't talking about JS, I was talking about PHP in your **functions.php** file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code can do the trick :

```
// The callback function for the action hook bellow
function any_script_in_footer()
{
    // Call the list with all the registered scripts
    global $wp_scripts;

    if ( isset ( $wp_scripts->registered ) && ! empty ( $wp_scripts->registered ) && is_array( $wp_scripts->registered ) ) {
        foreach ( $wp_scripts->registered as $idx => $script ) {
            if ( isset( $wp_scripts->registered[ $idx ]->extra ) && is_array( $wp_scripts->registered[ $idx ]->extra ) ) {

                // Set any of the scripts to belong in the footer group
                $wp_scripts->registered[ $idx ]->extra[ 'group' ] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Call the callback function with the `wp_print_scripts` hook at the very end 
// of the callbacks cue
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'any_script_in_footer', 1000);
```